# I'm working in Plone 4.3.1 and CSS

Tags: css, windows, plone

My computer is Windows and I am creating a website based on Plone. If I use the server runs as service, no problem, and the product is perfect, but if it stops and runs in the FG mode's symbol system page does not load the images but the rest of the information itself. Why does this happens?

Moreover, in DOS I get this message:

> IError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: ´C:\Plone43\var\blobstorage\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x00\0x30\0x30\0x3a29c2551641433.blob'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try to explain what you need, and what you did, spend sometime or your question to bring people to spend some of their time in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the system is running it as another user, and that this user has other permissions than you. I'm not sure of the best way to fix that in Windows, as you don't have sudo there, perhaps you need to give yourself more permissions on the Plone installation directory.